# Is it possible for a function to access and go through only one dimension of a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

Is it possible for a function to access and go through only one dimension of an array?

For example, I have 2D array and I want to give only the last column or one of the rows to a function with a single dimension like `int foo(int arr[],int len);` is there a way to make that work?

Comment: a 2-d array can be thought of as an array of arrays... you should show your declarations of arr and len. But yes, using one index into a 2-d array gets you an array. Is what you want truly a 'column' though, i.e. one element from each of the arrays? That requires transforming your data.

Comment: you can create a new array by iterating over your 2d array and only add the items from the last column to the recently created array then pass it to a function.

Comment: I see @RobP, I can't 'jump' through the pointers of the elements I assume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on is easier to understand with typedefs

```
 typedef int  INT10[10];    // INT10 is an alias for "an array of 10 ints"
 INT10 example;              // same as int example[10];

 INT10  myarray[20];    // defines 20 arrays of 10 ints each.

 int foo(INT10 segment, int length)
 {
       int a = segment[5];     //  6th element in given row
       // :
 }

 // :

int b = foo(myarray[3], 5);  // pass 4th row.
```

Now, we can remove the typedef (it was just a crutch):

```
 int  myarray[20][10];    // defines 20 arrays of 10 ints each.

 int foo(int segment[10], int length)
 {
```

Everything else is the same.

Now, to move this to the next level, `foo` doesn't really care the segment is 10 integers long, as long as you don't run off the end.  It really just getting a pointer anyway.

```
 int foo(int segment[], int length)
 {
```

Comment: I'll have to look up typedefs. Is `b` an array?

Comment: `foo` is defined as returning an int.  Therefore `b` is an int.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly; you'd have to make a new array from the elements.  Unless it were the last dimension; *that* is stored contiguously, and can be passed as you describe.